# Generic OAuth Flow

Tags: javascript, oauth, backend

I just have a quick question regarding the proper way to implement OAuth. I dont have any code or anything, just looking for some insight.

Say I would like to create a website that shows a list of your facebook friends. I serve up a page that uses facebook's OAuth to authenticate. The site redirect to facebook, you authorize my site access to your facebook account and then facebook returns an auth token in a redirect url.

Here is where the question lies. Should the site intercept the auth token from the redirect url in JavaScript and then just make an ajax request to facebook to pull the contacts and populate the page. Nothing hits my own backend here. I would image some things come into play here like CORS and such. Not to mention the application client and secret would be stored in the browser. But im not 100% certain.

Or Is the correct way to pass the authentication token to my backend server via the redirect url which processes the request to get a list of friends from facebook and then my backend sends me the contact information.

Thanks for all the insight.

Comment: I recently wrote blog post about how I solved it with Google OAuth. I can imagine Facebook works similar. I decided to put the logic on the backend. Maybe you'll find it useful - https://medium.com/@bogna.ka/integrating-google-oauth-with-express-application-f8a4a2cf3fee#.lca2j99no . I'm not 100% sure about my approach but I'm open to any suggestions.